# Automatically backport python 2.7 to 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, sed, backport

I need to run some Python 2.7 code under Python 2.6 and I was wondering how that could be automated.

Some specific simple changes are

```
sed -i -e 's/:,d/:d/g' -e 's/{0}/set([0])/g' foo.py
```

However, I also need to replace

```
with open(foo) as f, open(bar) as b:
    ...
```

with

```
with open(foo) as f:
 with open(bar) as b:
    ...
```

and it is much less obvious for me (I need to get the indentation right and my `sed`-foo is not enough here).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there really that many `with x, y` statements in your codebase that it's worth automating their replacement rather than simply automating their discovery?  I don't think `sed` is up for this job in the general case--you'd likely want to use Python's own `AST` module or similar--something that understands Python indentation for real.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I hoped someone already has something for this; we could do it manually, of course, but I think automated is more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't use `sed`. What you need is an IDE that understands refactoring or macros. For example, here's what I would do in `vim`:

- Search for the `with A as a, with B as B:` pattern
- Start recording a macro `qa`
- Find the comma `f,`
- Replace it with a colon `r:`
- Delete the space then enter a newline `lx<enter>`
- Tab or use spaces to indent
- Press `q` to stop recording

Then you iterate through the searches and press `@a` to replay the macro.

Comment: This assumes that I want the changes to be permanent (as in committed to git). I don't want that.

Comment: @sds If you are using git what's the problem? Create a branch designed specifically for the Python 2.6 code. Branches are decentralized so you never have to push the code.